# Swift: Invalid parameter not satisfying: metrics.count

Tags: swift, xcode

Getting this error

```
Invalid parameter not satisfying: metrics.count !=0 (NSInternalconsistencyException)
```

For the part its referring to

```
let time: [XCUMetric] = []
measure(metrics: time) {
XCUIApplication().launch()
}
```

Couldn’t figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The error is stating that the `measure` function expects a non-empty array of values. Your code is passing in an empty array. Add one or more values to the `time` array before passing it to the `metrics` parameter of the `measure` function.

Maybe you want to use an instance of `XCTClockMetric`.

```
let time: [XCTMetric] = [ XCTClockMetric() ]
measure(metrics: time) {
    XCUIApplication().launch()
}
```